# Publishing Google Sheets Addon - site verification

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-oauth, google-apps-script-addon

I've built a Google Sheets script that queries my company's API and outputs the data from my platform into a spreadsheet. It takes the username and password using a form and then runs an API call to output the results to Google Sheets.

When I tried to publish the addon, I received feedback that I needed to comply with Google OAuth verification. To get this verification, I need to prove that the domain is mine; although I have access to GA for our site (which isn't working for the verification), I am not the domain owner. So, I was wondering, is there a way to publish this Google addon for my company account and what are the next steps to complying with Google OAuth?

Comment: In the Script Editor, click Publish - Register in Chrome Web Store and follow the steps outlined there. After you have deployed the app, use the Chrome Store link to verify it.  Note that this doesn't work for file-bound scripts of any kind - your file must be a standalone GAS project

Comment: What do you mean by "GA for our site"?

Comment: That would likely be Google Admin for Anant's domain.